# Using blind vias for fanouts in GND and power planes

Tags: speed, bga, fanout

I am designing high density board with high pins count BGA, and hundreds of decoupling capacitors, in that what are the recommendations for using blind vias for fanouts to connect power and GND planes. Should I use blind vias or regular vias to avoid EMI/EMC issues?

Comment: The chip vendor probably provides a recommended layout for their chip. Have you read it?